# Javascript Currying Infinite Levels

Tags: javascript, currying

I recently saw some code that I just found out is called currying, I think.
The code looks like this:

```
layer.components[0]("ADBE Propety1")("ADBE Property 2")("ADBE Property 3");
```

The part I am interested in duplicating is the multiple sets of parenthesis after `components[0]`. Currying is new to me (as of today) and closures can get complicated. So I need some help.

I would like to create a class where an instance of that class has children and I can get to the children by name like this:

```
let bins = new Bins(proj);
console.log(bins('Videos')('More')('NiteLite_90.mp4')); 
// Return: {name: 'NiteLite_90.mp4', children: []}
```

With the code below, I can get two levels deep (down to 'More'), but not anywhere past that. I want to be able to go infinite levels deep.

```
class Bins {
  constructor(proj) {
    this.bins = this._getBins(proj);
  }

  bin(name) {
    let bin = this.bins.filter(b => b.name === name)[0];
    if (bin) {
      return (name) => bin.children.filter(b => b.name === name)[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  _getBins(proj) {
    let { children } = proj;
    let childs = [];
    let self = this;
    children.forEach(child => {
      let obj = { name: child.name };
      if (child.children && child.children.length > 0) {
        obj.children = self._getChildren(child);
      }
      childs.push(obj);
    });
    return childs;
  }

  _getChildren(child) {
    let children = [];
    let self = this;
    child.children.forEach(c => {
      let obj = { name: c.name };
      if (c.children && c.children.length > 0) {
        obj.children = self._getChildren(c);
      }
      children.push(obj);
    });
    return children;
  }
}

let proj = {
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Videos',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'NiteLite_00.mp4',
          children: []
        },
        {
          name: 'More',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'NiteLite_90.mp4',
              chidlren: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'NiteLite_97.mp4',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Sequences',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Oregon Coast',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    { name: 'Music', children: [] },
  ]
};
let bins = new Bins(proj);
console.log(bins.bin('Videos')('More')('NiteLite_90.mp4')); // I don't want to have to call `.bins` first
```

Could I get some help on setting this up?
I have researched multiple other currying posts on here and seen several blogs about it, but I still don't get it and I want some specific help with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a recursive curry function to be able to go as deep as you want. But you have an additional problem: how do you know when to stop returning a function and to return the actual object?

If you call `bins.bin('Video')('More')` -- how do you know if you want to return the bin for the `More` object or a function that will search through children of `More` so you can find the `'NiteLite_90.mp4` bin?

Below is one possible solution that will give you both options:

```
class Bins {
  search(collection, name) {
    const bin = collection.find(b => b.name === name);
    if (bin) {
      // first create a function that will search through this bin's children
      const curry = (name) => this.search(bin.children, name);

      // but make the bin itself available through a `.bin` property on the function
      curry.bin = bin;

      // return this new function so it can be curried
      return curry;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  bin(name) {
    return this.search(this.bins, name);
  }

  // plus everything you already have in this class, except for the original
  // bin(name) function
}
```

Now you can go an unlimited number of levels deep, and have access to any intermediate bin as well via the `.bin` property:

```
let bins = new Bins(proj);

console.log(bins.bin('Videos').bin);
// { name: "Videos", children: [ ... ] }

console.log(bins.bin('Videos')('More').bin);
// { name: "More", children: [ ... ] }

console.log(bins.bin('Videos')('More')('NiteLite_90.mp4').bin);
// { name: "NiteLite_90.mp4" }
```

Like your original method, the `search` method can return `null` so take care when you're searching for a path that might not exist:

```
console.log(bins.bin('Videos')('DoesNotExist')('NiteLite_90.mp4').bin);
// Uncaught TypeError: bins.bin(...)(...) is not a function

console.log(bins.bin('Videos')('More')('DoesNotExist.mp4').bin);
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bin' of null
```

So you'll probably want to wrap such calls in a `try/catch` to be safe:

```
let bin;
try {
  bin = bins.bin('Videos')('DoesNotExist')('NiteLite_90.mp4').bin;
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Bin not found!');
}

if (bin) {
  // do whatever you want with the found bin
}
```

Comment: Haha! This is exactly what I needed! What a beautiful solution. Thank you, @rickdenhaan. I appreciate you taking time to write this out and be so thorough.

Comment: No problem, I though it was an interesting challenge :)

Comment: Also, if this will help anyone in the future, I changed `return null` to `return { bin: null }` so that I wouldn't get an error thrown if a bin wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function, which returns itself:

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(){
    function bar(){
      //Do something nice here
      return bar
    }
    this.bar=bar
  }
}

new Foo().bar(1)(2)(3)
```

Now, you can go infinitely deep...

```
new Foo().bar(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)(13)(14)(15)(16)(17)(18)(19)(20) //Works perfectly
```

Ok, but how to collect data of all calls?

This is where it start to get tricky.

1. You can store somthing after each call on the 'owner' object of the function:

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(){
    function bar(arg){
      baz.push(arg)
      return bar
    }
    const baz=[]
    this.bar=bar
    this.baz=baz
  }
}

const foo=new Foo()
foo.bar(1)(2)(3)

console.log(foo.baz) //[1,2,3]
```

2. Or, pass some information between subsequent calls by `bind`ing `this` to the returned function, like this:

```js
class Foo{
  constructor(){
    function bar(...args){
      console.log(this)
      return bar.bind(
        this //Bound array
        .concat(args)
      )
    }
    this.bar=bar.bind([])
  }
}

new Foo().bar(1)(2)(3)()
//[]
//[1]
//[1,2]
//[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
class Animal {
  constructor (name) {
    console.log(`Im a bear called ${name}`)
  }

  shout (voice) {
    return (sound) => `I am making a ${sound} sound with a ${voice} voice` ;
  }
}

const harry = new Animal('Harry')
const speakUp = harry.shout('low')('woof')

console.log(speakUp)
```

#### Small explanation

The whole idea of currying is that functions return functions. So whereas you normally would do something like:

```
const hello = (name, age, job) => (
  `My nam is ${name}, I am ${age} and I do ${job} for a living`
)
```

with currying you'd do something like:

```
const hello = (name, age, job) => (
  `My nam is ${name}, I am ${age} and I do ${job} for a living`
)

const helloWithCurrying = (name) => (age) => (job) => (
  `My nam is ${name}, I am ${age} and I do ${job} for a living`
)

console.log(hello('Rick', 26, 'coding'))
console.log(helloWithCurrying('Rick')(26)('coding'))
```

The benefit of currying really comes into play when you are having complex Higher Order Functions.

Comment: Unless you have some code that's been adapted to be composable like the OP is asking, please leave this as a comment. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am not looking for a general tutorial on currying, I am looking for how to curry in as deep as there are layers in the example that I put above so that I don't have to write 20+ closure functions in my code.